# Split list in sublists based on OOP

Tags: c#, list, oop, sublist

In C#, given a list of objects

Is there a way to create sublists by the number of each object from that list of objects?

Example:

Input:

Main list:

```
Object A= {"Erick", "Cartman", 3}
Object B= {"Angelina", "Jollie", 4}
Object C= {"Anton", "Azul", 4}
Object D= {"Random", "Data", 5}
```

Output:

Sublist 1:

```
Object A= {"Erick", "Cartman", 3}
```

Sublist 2:

```
Object B= {"Angelina", "Jollie", 4}   // this sublist will only have number 4 objects
Object C= {"Anton", "Azul", 4}
```

Sublist 3:

```
Object D= {"Random", "Data", 5}
```

Consider that the main list may contain more than 1000 objects, therefore, theres no way to tell how many sublists are going to pop out

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: [Group query results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Comment: The main issue was creating the sublists by different number, cause i had a .CSV file where i must group sublists by a code. Which i've never done. The closest was with a known value, but that code has a length of a lot of chars

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp , that was incredible and that is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<Object>> list = new List<List<Object>>();
int currentnumber; 
List<Object> currentList = new List<Object>();   
foreach(object a in objects)
{
if(a.Number != currentnumber)
{
currentnumber = a.Number; 
currentList = new List<Object>();
currentList.Add(a);
list.Add(currentList)

}
else
{
currentList.Add(a);
}



}
```

Something like this would work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).